# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied in Unet2DConditionModel

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, unet-neural-network

Today i try to use Unet2DConditionModel and CLIPTextModel from Transformer Library with my text to image dataset, but i have error "RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (4928x768 and 1280x128)". I can't undestand how to fix this.

Prepare dataset:

```py
from transformers import CLIPTextModel, CLIPTokenizer
tokenizer = CLIPTokenizer.from_pretrained("openai/clip-vit-large-patch14")
text_encoder = CLIPTextModel.from_pretrained("openai/clip-vit-large-patch14")
text_encoder = text_encoder.to(device)

class T2IMinecraft(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image_folder, txt_file, transform=None):
        self.image_folder = image_folder
        self.txt_file = txt_file
        self.transform = transform
        self.img_paths = []
        self.text_desc = []

        with open(txt_file, 'r') as f:
          for line in f.readlines():
            img_dir, text = line.lower().strip().split(' | ')
            img_path = os.path.join(self.image_folder, img_dir)
            text = tokenizer(text, padding="max_length", max_length=tokenizer.model_max_length, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
            self.img_paths.append(img_path)
            self.text_desc.append(text)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.img_paths)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_path = self.img_paths[idx]
        img = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGBA')

        if self.transform:
          img = self.transform(img)

        text_desc = self.text_desc[idx]
        with torch.no_grad():
          text_tensor = text_encoder(text_desc.input_ids.to(device))[0]
        text_tensor = torch.squeeze(text_tensor)
        return img, text_tensor

preprocess = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((64, 64)), transforms.ToTensor(),])
T2I = T2IMinecraft('data', 'data/metadata.txt', preprocess)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(T2I, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
```

Unet2DConditionModel:

```py
from diffusers import UNet2DConditionModel

model = UNet2DConditionModel(
    sample_size=64,
    in_channels=4,
    out_channels=4,
    layers_per_block=2,
    block_out_channels=(128, 320, 640, 640),
    down_block_types=(
        "CrossAttnDownBlock2D",
        "CrossAttnDownBlock2D",
        "CrossAttnDownBlock2D",
        "DownBlock2D",
    ),
    up_block_types=(
        "UpBlock2D",
        "CrossAttnUpBlock2D",
        "CrossAttnUpBlock2D",
        "CrossAttnUpBlock2D",
    ),
)
model.to(device);
```

Train step:

```py
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

losses = []
grad_accumulation_steps = 2

for epoch in range(500):
    print(f"Epoch:{epoch}")
    for step, (img, txt_desc) in tqdm(enumerate(train_dataloader), total=len(train_dataloader)):
        clean_images = img.to(device)
        txt_desc = txt_desc.to(device)
        noise = torch.randn(clean_images.shape).to(clean_images.device)
        bs = clean_images.shape[0]

        timesteps = torch.randint(0, noise_scheduler.num_train_timesteps, (bs,), device=clean_images.device).long()

        noisy_images = noise_scheduler.add_noise(clean_images, noise, timesteps)

        noise_pred = model(noisy_images, timesteps, encoder_hidden_states=txt_desc, return_dict=False) 

        loss = F.mse_loss(noise_pred, noise)
        loss.backward(loss)
        losses.append(loss.item())

        if (step + 1) % grad_accumulation_steps == 0:
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
```

Error i have in line: noise_pred = model(noisy_images, timesteps, encoder_hidden_states=txt_desc, return_dict=False)

Full error dump

```py
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-cc98681ecb24> in <cell line: 6>()
     16         noisy_images = noise_scheduler.add_noise(clean_images, noise, timesteps)
     17 
---> 18         noise_pred = model(noisy_images, timesteps, encoder_hidden_states=txt_desc, return_dict=False)
     19 
     20         loss = F.mse_loss(noise_pred, noise)

13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
    112 
    113     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 114         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    115 
    116     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (4928x768 and 1280x128)
```

Shape of img torch.Size([64, 4, 64, 64])
Shape of text description torch.Size([64, 77, 768]

Comment: take a look at the shape of noisy_images before calling the model with them.. and give us the full error stack dump, it could help

Comment: @AndreiPop i add error dump. noisy_images have shape size ([64,4,64,64])

Comment: I think it is because this text encoder is not supposed to be paste in this UNet as is because the dimensions of the two models mismatch. Two possibilities:
1) Try `cross_attention_dim=768` in the UNet config
2) Add a dense layer on the output of the encoder `nn.Linear(768, 1280)` and retrain it with the rest of the UNet maybe

Comment: @ValentinGoldité I try use `cross_attention_dim=768` and it help me to fix old error, but now i have error with out of memory. I try to reduce batch size or edit Unet2DConditionModel config, but the memory error remains the same. However, it always sounds the same: “2 MB of memory is missing”